# Why do we not use these helping verbs (do, did and does) in positive sentences?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I need to know why we do not use these helping verbs (*do, did and does*) in positive sentences. Let me give you some examples to explain it in a much better way.

> He works *(positive)*.
>
> He **does** not work *(negative)*.
>
> **Does** he work? *(question)*.

How would the meaning be changed if I rewrote the same sentence using *does*?

> He **does** work.

Answer (score 4):

When *DO* is used in an ordinary declarative (positive) sentence it expresses emphatic assertion, usually in contrast to a prior negative. In speech it receives primary stress.

> Jill is too shy to work well on teams, but she **does** work well on her own.
>
> **Speaker A:** Jack doesn't work here any more.
> **Speaker B:** He **does** work here, but he's on the night shift.

In older English the *DO* forms were employed more freely, alternating with simple present and past. You will find it frequently in Shakespeare:

> O she doth teach the torches to burn bright!
>
> Why, man, they did make love to this employment.

But it had largely disappeared from the Standard dialect by the 18th century, and survives today only in dialects.